Best Framework for Implementing Multi-Compartment SNN with Meta-Plasticity on BrainScaleS-2: PyNN or hsTorch?
I’m developing a spiking neural network (SNN) in PyTorch, where each neuron has multiple compartments. These compartments feature non-linear signals. They are have their own internal dynamics but are a function of other non-linear signals. Moreover, synapses use custom plasticity rules that differ from conventional ones like Hebbian plasticity. I also plan to add meta-plasticity rules and additional plasticity rules for specific compartments, which would involve tracking these non-linear signals over time.
Given these requirements and my target hardware (the BrainScaleS-2 neuromorphic chip), which framework would be better suited for implementation: PyNN or hsTorch?
Key concerns:

Tracking non-linear signals: Each compartment needs a way to store and manage non-linear signals. How well can PyNN or hsTorch address this on BrainScaleS-2?
Plasticity flexibility
Managing the interfacing and communication of digital circuit inputs to a neuromorphic chip for processing

TLDR: I’m looking for advice on the best modeling framework to optimize both signal tracking and plasticity implementation on BrainScaleS-2.
